# What does 「な」 in 「降りなよ」 mean in this context?

Tags: syntax

The title of a Take Free magazine I picked up at Shimokitazawa is

> とりあえず、シモキタで　降りなよ

What does 「な」 in 「降りなよ」 mean in this context?

I'm sure it isn't a negative; *not* dropping off by Shimokitazawa.

Comment: 「降りな」 is affirmative;「降りるな」 is negative.  Ain't no way a magazine promoting a particular area would tell you NOT to get off the train there, is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use of 「な」 is simply a contracted form of the imperative construction ～なさい that attaches to the stem form (連用形) of a verb.

[See definition 1.2 at goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/162229/m1u/%E3%81%AA/):

> 《補助動詞「なさる」の命令形「なさい」の省略形》
>
> 動詞・動詞型助動詞の連用形に付く。命令の意を表す。
>
> 「早く行き―」「好きなようにやり―」

So, as you suspected, it does not mean "don't such-and-such", but rather "*do* such-and-such".

I'm not sure that "drop off by" makes sense here as a translation of 降りる - "get off at" Shimokitazawa seems more likely, assuming there is a train station or something nearby.

Comment: It is definitely about getting off the train.  The trains are by far the main method of transportation in Tokyo, where Shimokitazawa is located.